# Trigonometric Identity problem involving cot

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Simplify $\displaystyle\frac{\cot25 + \tan65}{\cot25}$

My attempt is:

$$\frac{\cot25 + \tan65}{\cot25}=\frac{\cot25 + \cot(90 - 65)}{\cot25}=\frac{\cot25 + \cot25}{\cot25}= \frac{\cot50}{\cot25}$$

and that is all I got up to.. The correct answer is $2$, I know that $\cot 50$ goes into $\cot 25$ twice. But, I'm not sure if my method is right.

Comment: $\displaystyle\frac{\cot 25 + \cot 25}{\cot 25} = 2$

Generally speaking, $\cot a + \cot a \neq \cot 2a$

Comment: It becomes that you don't know that $\cot 50$ is not $\cot 25$ 2 times.

Comment: @DarthGeek Ok thank you, do you know where I can find other rules like you mentioned, in dealing with multiplication, subtraction, division etc with "cot, sin, tan, cosec...etc". ? They are not treated as normal integers, thus I do not know how to deal with them.

Comment: Instead, it would be $\large \frac {2\times(\cot 25)}{\cot 25}$ in the last step.

Comment: Good ol' Wikipedia always helps:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: @DarthGeek Sorry for being bad, but where exactly in the article?

Comment: Well, about dealing with sum and product of trigonometric identities here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities

And here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Just look at this :* 
$$ \frac{\cot25 + \tan65}{\cot25} = 1+\frac{\tan65}{\cot25} = 1+\frac{\tan(90-25)}{\cot25} = 1+\frac{\cot25}{\cot25} = 1+1 = 2$$. Did you get it ??

Comment: Where did 1 come from?

Comment: Nvm, understood it.